# Google APIs Client Library for Java or Google Drive for accessing Google calendar / tasks from Android

Tags: android, task, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to sync data from Google calendar and tasks to **Android** and was wondering what is the best way . I have found:

Google APIs Client Library for Java (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

and

Google Drive

If there a difference between the two? (https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Calendar events and Tasks are not related to Google Drive at all. There are separate libraries for the three:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API
- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API
- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Tasks_API

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should mention I'm looking to connect from Android and trying to determine the *best* way to connect to Google Tasks and calendar.

Comment: Those libraries would be the best way, IMO. Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fBcrzA-hWY and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dylFNrvZ_3U